# cart rule condition based on price including tax

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, tax

I want to create a rule that gives people a discount of 10% if the subtotal of the cart is over $100.

I have this rule working but with one problem, to check weather the cart is over $100 it is using the subtotal without tax were I want it to use the subtotal with tax.

The condition I am using is pictured below.

[image]

I have looked into changing Configuration -> Sales -> Tax settings but most of these settings are already set how I need them for the rest of the site. There are also some products with and without tax so I cannot try and cheat my way by using a lower number.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue with magento 2.2.2.

When you create a cart rule and you select **Subtotal** as cart attribute condition you are choosing the html option value `value="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address|base_subtotal"`.

It means that the cart rule will use the `quote_address.base_subtotal` column to validate the coupon's condition.

If your catalog has the **Catalog Prices** option (Stores->Configuration->Sales->Tax->Calculation Settings) setted to **Excluding Tax** the `quote_address.base_subtotal` will contain subtotal WITHOUT tax.

Now, digging in the magento core i found that the cart rule condition is validated in `vendor/magento/module-rule/Model/Condition/AbstractCondition.php` with `validate()` method.

To fix the issue, i changed the code in

```
...
$attr = $this->getAttribute();
if ($attr == "base_subtotal") $attr = "base_subtotal_total_incl_tax";

$attributeValue = $model->getData($attr);

return $this->validateAttribute($attributeValue);
...
```

so, `quote_address.base_subtotal_total_incl_tax` will be used instead of `quote_address.base_subtotal`.

**PS1**: i also tried a lot on the web to find a solution and i did not find anything

**PS2**: i changed and suggested how to fix the issue directly in the core file, but it is a bad pratice, take your precautions :)

Answer (score 0):

This is is fixed by patch [MDVA-31399](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052496872-MDVA-31399-Magento-patch-adds-Subtotal-Incl-Tax-to-cart-price-rule-condition). If you apply this patch it gives a new discount condition "Subtotal (Incl. Tax)", which explicitly includes tax when triggering discounts.

The problem is discussed on the GitHub issue tracker here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29740 Suggests that it will be available in 2.3.7 which has not been released at the time of answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also check check this configuration

[image]

I hope this will help.